# AngularJs's ng-options - clarification?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this small [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UPWKe/22/).

Basically  , it's a `select` element with this data :

```
 address: {
            select: {
                code: "0",
                name: "Select proof of address"
            },
            letter: {
                code: "1",
                name: "Letter"
            },
            photograph: {
                code: "2",
                name: "Photograph"
            }
        }
```

And here is the `select`

```
 <select ng-model="current.addressCode" ng-options="value.code as value.name for (key,value) in student.address"</select>
```

**Questions:**

**Question #1** -  Looking at the Ng doc -

[image]

And so , I try to compare

`value.code as value.name for (key,value) in student.address`

to the second line ( which i find most appropriate)

```
select as label for (key , value) in object
```

What is going on here ?

`value.code` goes to `select` ???

Html `select` element has an `option` tag with `value` and inside `text` like :

`<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>` thats' all.

What did they mean in their docs ?

**Question #2**

How can I bind this object of myne  to a regular sane `value,text` select ?

(I want the `code` to be the `value` and the `name` to be as `text`)

Currently I dont see any value in the dom :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in understanding that example two fits your needs, that is:

```
select as label for (key , value) in object
```

Here, as the documentation mentions:

```
select: The result of this expression will be bound to the model of the 
        parent <select> element. If not specified, select expression will
        default to value.
```

So, for your use case, your existing code for the select tag is correctly structured:

```
<select ng-model="current.addressCode" ng-options="value.code as value.name for
        (key,value) in student.address"></select>
```

`value.code` value is stored in `current.addressCode` while, in the select dropdown, you should see `value.name` as the options label.

EDIT: So, to answer your questions:
**Question 1**
In this case, "select" is just a variable name - a placeholder if you may like for the documentation to explain about it (which it does further below). In your code, the value of the variable that is used instead of select is the one that gets bound to the select's `ng-model` (In your case, value.code)

**Question 2**
Exactly as you have mentioned:

```
<select ng-model="current.addressCode" ng-options="value.code as value.name for
            (key,value) in student.address"></select>
```

This will give you the necessary value, text select tag automatically. When you select an option, the `value.code` associated with that option gets stored in `current.addressCode`

Comment: So why I dont see the value when I do "inspect element" ?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7FL76/1/

how about this:

it requires simple change :

```
 address: [
            {
                code: "0",
                name: "Select proof of address"
            },
            {
                code: "1",
                name: "Letter"
            },
            {
                code: "2",
                name: "Photograph"
            }
        ]
```

the reason is your **Key** is same as nested **Name** ( like, letter - Letter ) , so json is a bit redundant.

as result you will see.

value as a **code**, and text as a **name** .